# Content security policy issue on logout (.NET Core)

Tags: .net, angular, asp.net-core, cors

I have a security headers middleware in my .NET Core app.

Here is the middleware class:

```
public sealed class SecurityHeaders
{
    private const string CspHeader = "Content-Security-Policy";
    private const string SwaggerPage = "swagger/index.html";

    private readonly RequestDelegate next;

    public SecurityHeaders(RequestDelegate next) => this.next = next;

    public Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
    {
        context.Response.Headers.Add("X-XSS-Protection", "1; mode=block");
        context.Response.Headers.Add("X-Content-Type-Options", "nosniff");
        context.Response.Headers.Add("X-Frame-Options", "SAMEORIGIN");
        context.Response.Headers.Add("Referrer-Policy", "strict-origin");

        if (!context.Response.Headers.ContainsKey(CspHeader)
            && context.Request.Path.HasValue
            && !context.Request.Path.Value.EndsWith(SwaggerPage))
        {
            context.Response.Headers.Add(
                CspHeader,
                string.Join(
                    "; ",
                    new List<string>
                    {
                        "default-src 'self'",

                        // Don't remove 'unsafe-inline'. Need for Angular https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/6361
                        "style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'",

                        // Don't remove  img-src *;. Need for 'favicons' functionality
                        // data: needed for kendo-editor inline svgs
                        "img-src * data:",
                        "font-src 'self' data:",
                        "frame-src 'self' https://localhost:5002 https://*.website.com https://login.microsoftonline.com",
                        "frame-ancestors 'self'"
                    }));
        }

        return this.next(context);
    }
}
```

This is how I add it to the `Startup.cs` file:

```
 app.UseCorrelationId("MyHome_WebApi_{0}")
       .UseDefaultExceptionsHandling()
       .UseHttpsRedirection()
       .UseHsts()
       .UseAuthentication()
       .UseMiddleware<SecurityHeaders>()
       .UseMiddleware<UserHandling>()
       .UseMiddleware<DisableAuthPageCachingMiddleware>()
       .UseMiddleware<ErrorHandlingMiddleware>()
       .UseStaticFiles()
       .UseAzureAppConfiguration()
       .UseResponseCompression();
```

And I have a controller method for logout

```
[ApiVersion("1.0")]
[Route("v{version:apiVersion}/[controller]/[action]")]
public class AuthController : ServiceEnvironmentControllerBase
{
    public AuthController(IServiceEnvironment<IHomeBLLContext> environment,
                          IExceptionProcessor exceptionProcessor,
                          IExternalSystems externalSystems,
                          ILogger<AuthController> logger)
        : base(environment, exceptionProcessor, externalSystems, logger)
    {
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public async Task LogOut()
    {
        await this.HttpContext.SignOutAsync();
    }
}
```

When I try to call the controller method from the Angular application, I get this error in the console:

> Refused to connect to 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/df7fa6cf-2f69-491d-bacd-8caa90484c7b/oauth2/logout' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "default-src 'self'". Note that 'connect-src' was not explicitly set, so 'default-src' is used as a fallback.

If I change `frame-src` to `connect-src` I got this

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/df7fa6cf-2f69-491d-bacd-8caa90484c7b/oauth2/logout' (redirected from 'https://localhost:5002/Services/WebApi/v1/Auth/LogOut') from origin 'https://localhost:5002' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

How I can fix this?

Comment: try enable cors follow this document:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/cors?view=aspnetcore-8.0#cors-with-named-policy-and-middleware